# Shopify : Is it possible to Sort Collection by date product is UPDATED rather than CREATED

Tags: shopify

is it possible to sort a collection by the date a product has been updated rather than the original creation date?

For instance if a product sells out, but then I add some new stock later, i'd like it to reappear at the top of the sorted list, rather than always being tied to the original creation date.

Can this be done using any sort of custom script?